# Extract only the month in a query CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a query where I get people birthday's in a current month, I have problems with MONTH() it does not work for me, the date format in the database is: 04/18/1990, and I want to compare if the month current date('m') is equal to the month of the database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which data type is you date column ??  string or datetime ?

Comment: Hello is string

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where extract(month from BirthDate) = date("m");
```

where date("m") return current month and BirthDate is column name in which you have stored birthdate.

Answer (score 0):

could be you have some convertion issue  try using

```
 select  month(str_to_date(my_col, '%m/%d/%Y'))
 from my_table  
 where   month(str_to_date(my_col, '%m/%d/%Y')) = month(now())
```

Comment: I get the following error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'str_to_date'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"select  month(str_to_date(birthdate), '%Y/%m/%d')
from users  
where month(str_to_date(birthdate), '%Y/%m/%d') = '$month'"
```

Here, i m assuming your delimeter is '/', Please set your delimeter according to your string date i.e `2013/05/04` or `2013,05,04` or `2013-05-04`